# Oracle: Finding Primary Keys - PK and NN

Tags: database, oracle, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I am working with a database and was told the Table `USERS` has a single Primary Key - `USERID`. Using `ALL_CONS_COLS` gives me the following:

```
OWNER   | TABLE_NAME | CONSTRAINT_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | POSITION
----------------------------------------------------------------
MONSTER |   USERS    |   USER_ID_PK    |   USERREF   |   2
MONSTER |   USERS    |   USER_ID_NN    |   USERID
MONSTER |   USERS    |   USER_ID_PK    |   USERID    |   1
```

This suggests the `PK` is a composite comprised of: `USERREF` and `USERID`.

There are a few things I do not follow:

Why does `USERID` have both a `NOT NULL` constraint and also a `PK` constraint? `PK` by definition means `NN`.
Secondly, as `USERID` has a `NN` constraint, why does `USERREF` not have a `NN` constraint?
Thirdly, why is `CONSTRAINT_NAME` "suggesting" the `PK` is `USER_ID` (`USERID`), i.e., why is the constraint named after a single column; wouldn't `USERS_PK` be a better constraint name?

So, ultimately, is it a Composite `PK` or not?

Comment: The answer to most of those questions is (probably): because someone created it that way (especially the names and NN constraints)

Comment: Thanks! So is it a Composite `PK`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, ultimately, is it a Composite PK or not?

Yes. The primary key is defined on two columns together. The position will tell you the leading column. `USER_ID_PK` primary key constraint is defined on `USERID` as leading column followed by `USERREF`.

> Why does USERID have both a NOT NULL constraint and also a PK constraint?

Because someone created a **NOT NULL** constraint on the **primary key** column explicitly.

Let's test and see.

**Single primary key**

```
SQL> create table t(a number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> SELECT a.table_name,
  2    b.column_name,
  3    a.constraint_type,
  4    b.position
  5  FROM user_constraints a
  6  JOIN user_cons_columns b
  7  ON a.owner             = b.owner
  8  AND a.constraint_name  = b.constraint_name
  9  AND a.table_name       = b.table_name
 10  AND a.constraint_type IN ('P', 'C');

TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAM C   POSITION
---------- ---------- - ----------
T          A          P          1
```

**Composite primary key**

```
SQL> drop table t purge;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table t(a number, b number);

Table created.

SQL> alter table t add constraint t_pk PRIMARY KEY(a,

Table altered.

SQL> SELECT a.table_name,
  2    b.column_name,
  3    a.constraint_type,
  4    b.position
  5  FROM user_constraints a
  6  JOIN user_cons_columns b
  7  ON a.owner             = b.owner
  8  AND a.constraint_name  = b.constraint_name
  9  AND a.table_name       = b.table_name
 10  AND a.constraint_type IN ('P', 'C');

TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAM C   POSITION
---------- ---------- - ----------
T          A          P          1
T          B          P          2
```

**Primary key and NOT NULL**

```
SQL> drop table t purge;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table t(a number primary key not null);

Table created.

SQL> SELECT a.table_name,
  2    b.column_name,
  3    a.constraint_type,
  4    b.position
  5  FROM user_constraints a
  6  JOIN user_cons_columns b
  7  ON a.owner             = b.owner
  8  AND a.constraint_name  = b.constraint_name
  9  AND a.table_name       = b.table_name
 10  AND a.constraint_type IN ('P', 'C');

TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAM C   POSITION
---------- ---------- - ----------
T          A          C
T          A          P          1
```

Comment: What is a _leading column_ and what effect does it have (if any)?

Comment: By "leading column" I mean the first column in this context. However, it has it's significance in a concatenated(composite) index. It is out of scope of  your question. Still, if you are interested, have a look at http://www.orafaq.com/tuningguide/concatenated%20indexes.html